# Wireless USB Adapter not detected

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit does not detect a USB WiFi adapter that according to the packaging is supposed to work for Linux. Windows 10 picks it up straight away.

WIFI Model: COMFAST CF-826F

```
$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 18f8:0fc0 [Maxxter] USB GAMING MOUSE 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 258a:002a SINO WEALTH Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:f192 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n  WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.11.0-38-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: B450 AORUS M v: x.x serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: F51 date: 07/29/2020 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 86237 
  Speed: 2194 MHz min/max: 2200/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2195 2: 2195 
  3: 2192 4: 2195 5: 2196 6: 2195 7: 2196 8: 2237 9: 2196 10: 2198 11: 2190 
  12: 2195 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU116 [GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER] vendor: Gigabyte 
  driver: nvidia v: 470.63.01 bus ID: 06:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa tty: N/A 
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2 
  v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.63.01 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU116 High Definition Audio vendor: Gigabyte 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 06:00.1 
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 08:00.4 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-38-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Gigabyte driver: r8169 v: kernel port: f000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek 802.11n WLAN Adapter type: USB driver: usb-network 
  bus ID: 1-6:2 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 10.72 GiB (1.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Silicon Power model: SPCC Solid State Disk 
  size: 953.87 GiB temp: 40 C 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 137.41 GiB used: 10.69 GiB (7.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 59.4 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 50 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 59% 
Info:
  Processes: 313 Uptime: 12m Memory: 15.58 GiB used: 2.06 GiB (13.2%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a working internet connection by tethering, ethernet or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8192fu-dkms
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192fu-dkms
sudo dkms build rtl8192fu/5.8.6.2
sudo dkms install rtl8192fu/5.8.6.2
```

It builds with a few possibly harmless warnings on my 21.10 system. Reboot.